# Solving exponential equation: $-6+3e^x=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-6+3e^x=8$$

First I added the $6$ to both sides.  Then I could see that this was in exponential form so I did the logarithmic form to both sides. Getting an answer of $2.401$.  I am hoping I did this right so I can explain it to my son.  Help...

Comment: Usually the answer should be exact (instead of a decimal approximation) unless specified otherwise. It sounds like you're doing the right thing but there's a step you left out in the post, so you should say the answer you got before approximating.

Comment: On this site we are expecting you to show how you arrived at your answer,  among other reasons in order to be able to pinpoint a mistake in case there is one.

Comment: You forgot to divide both sides by 3 before using logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}&-6+3e^x=8\,\;\;/\,+6\\
&3e^x=8+6=14\;\;/\;\;\div3\\
&e^x=\frac{14}3\;\;/\;\;\log\\
&x=\log\frac{14}3\cong1.54\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer not is (approximately) $2.401$. But the way you did it is correct, we have
\begin{align*}
   -6 + 3e^x &= 8\\
\iff 3e^x &= 14\\
\iff e^x &= \frac{14}3\\
\iff x &= \log \frac{14}3 \approx 1.5404
\end{align*}

Comment: If we're talking about a US high school here they'll probably say $\log$ is wrong and will want to see $\ln$.

Comment: @MattSamuel What denotes $\log$ then if not the natural logarithm?

Comment: $\log$ is the natural logarithm to mathematicians, but on a calculator it's base 10.

Comment: In the US log is use for base 10 logarithm. If you use log for some other base it would be noted like $\mathrm{log}_\mathrm{e}$ or $\mathrm{log}_\mathrm{2}$